# Why is my query never editing a member of my MySQL table properly?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a basic members only website, and one of my pages is meant to edit a user's information from an admin view. It accesses the the database named contacts, and then the table tblUsers, but somewhere along the line when it finally goes to edit the info it doesn't save.

```
<?php 
include("main.php");

connectDB();

//check for submit being pressed
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   //check for empty fields
    if($_POST['fName']!="" && $_POST['lName']!="" && $_POST['uName']!="" && $_POST['email']!="" && $_POST['address']!="" && $_POST['city']!="" && $_POST['state']!="" && $_POST['zip']!="" && $_POST['phone']!="" && $_POST['signup']!="")
    {
        $SQL="Update tblUsers SET firstName='".$_POST['fName']."', lastName='".$_POST['lName']."',userName='".$_POST['uName']."', email='".$_POST['email']."', address='".$_POST['address']."', city='".$_POST['city']."', state='".$_POST['state']."', zip='".$_POST['zip']."', phone='".$_POST['phone']."', signupDate='".$_POST['signup']."' WHERE userID=".$_POST['userID'];

        $response=mysql_query($SQL);
        //redirect with status update
        header("Location:editMember.php?id=".$_POST['userID']."&status=1");
    }
    else
    {   //redirect with status update
        header("Location:editMember.php?id=".$_POST['userID']."&status=2");
    }

}

//check for ID, if none redirect
if($_GET['id']=="")
{
    header("Location:adminView.php");
    exit;
}


//function to display form
function displayForm($strMessage, $userid, $response="")
{
    echo    "<center><strong>" . $strMessage . "</strong></center><br><br>";
    echo    "<form method=\"post\" action=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "\">\n";
    echo    "<table>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "First Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"fName\" value=\"" . mysql_result($response,0,"firstName") . "\">\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
            "</tr>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "Last Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"lName\" value=\"" . mysql_result($response,0,"lastName") . "\">\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
            "</tr>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"uName\" value=\"" . mysql_result($response,0,"username") . "\">\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
            "</tr>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "Email: <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" value=\"" . mysql_result($response,0,"email") . "\">\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
    echo    "</tr>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "Address: <input type=\"text\" name=\"address\" value=\"" . mysql_result($response,0,"address") . "\">\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
            "</tr>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "City: <input type=\"text\" name=\"city\" value=\"" . mysql_result($response,0,"city") . "\">\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
            "</tr>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "State: <input type=\"text\" name=\"state\" value=\"" . mysql_result($response,0,"state") . "\">\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
            "</tr>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "Zip: <input type=\"text\" name=\"zip\" value=\"" . mysql_result($response,0,"zip") . "\">\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
            "</tr>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "Phone Number: <input type=\"text\" name=\"phone\" value=\"" . mysql_result($response,0,"phone") . "\">\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
            "</tr>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "Sign-up Date: <input type=\"text\" name=\"signup\" value=\"" . mysql_result($response,0,"signupDate") . "\">\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
            "</tr>\n";
    echo    "<tr>\n";
    echo        "<td>\n";
    echo            "<center><input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" name=\"submit\"/></center>\n";
    echo        "</td>\n";
    echo    "</tr>\n";
    echo    "</table>\n";
    echo    "</form>\n";
}
//status switch to show message if successful edit
switch($_GET['status'])
{
    case 1:
    $strMessage="Changes have been saved";
    break;

    case 2:
    $strMessage="All fields are required.";
    break;

    default:
    $strMessage="Edit users.";
}
//query to show details of a user with specified userID
$SQL="SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE userid=".$_GET['id'];
$response=mysql_query($SQL);

if($response && mysql_num_rows($response) > 0)
{
    displayForm($strMessage,$_GET['id'],$response);
}
else
{
    header("Location:adminView.php");
}
?>

<html>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {border: 1px solid black; margin-left:auto; 
                        margin-right:auto;}
            tr {border: 1px solid black}
            td {border: 1px solid black;}
            body {background-color: orange;}
            *{font-family:Arial;}
        </style>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't use mysql_* functions in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1028804)

Comment: can't emphasize on this enough: check for errors in every possible way.

Comment: @Memor-X I understand that there may be problems with using mysql functions, however this is how I was taught to do it. I can only assume that there is a way to get this to work since it was assigned to me. This is for a basic PHP and MySQL class

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tried looking for errors all day, I have been sitting here for  like 3 hours not able to figure out what's going wrong, that is why I posted here.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: @TylerBobertson if you look at the question/answer i linked to you'll notice that `mysql_` is deprecated and is removed in later versions of PHP

Comment: @Fred-ii- The forced error reporting made me find out where my bug was, I was checking for userID at post, but I never posted userID in the form so it never changed anything. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

userID was looking for a posted value, but was never being posted in the form so nothing happened, question answered.